# EF poertools beta 2 - Pre-Generated Views dployment error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

We use EF powertools beta 2, with reverse engineering code first feature to generate our e
entities, the context and the views.
and we have the strange behavior, that in team on several machines the hash for the generated compiled views is different, and then on TFS team build same as on the other machines we get an exception like following.

Question is based on what the power tools is generating the hash for the compiled views ? and what we can change that it is consistent, we are using the power tools beta 2 with EF 4.3.1 , system.data .v4.0.30319 ,against an Oracle db using the devart oracle drivers.

context generate views

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.551
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if  the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: System.Data.Mapping.EntityViewGenerationAttribute(typeof(Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews.ViewsForBaseEntitySetsC6473E0A11A196A36CC5839589DE2DE553F202E361016A89F2142797168B2534))]

namespace Edm_EntityMappingGeneratedViews
{
    /// <Summary>
    /// The type contains views for EntitySets and AssociationSets that were generated at design time.
    /// </Summary>
    public sealed class ViewsForBaseEntitySetsC6473E0A11A196A36CC5839589DE2DE553F202E361016A89F2142797168B2534 : System.Data.Mapping.EntityViewContainer
    {

        /// <Summary>
        /// The constructor stores the views for the extents and also the hash values generated based on the metadata and mapping closure and views.
        /// </Summary>
        public ViewsForBaseEntitySetsC6473E0A11A196A36CC5839589DE2DE553F202E361016A89F2142797168B2534()
        {
            this.EdmEntityContainerName = "Context";
            this.StoreEntityContainerName = "CodeFirstDatabase";
            this.HashOverMappingClosure = "2c6bbce22db7c9c65f8a70c5a1bae1225522a2124aad50e74bdc186ce8c70508";
            this.HashOverAllExtentViews = "26cad9d7334571a0116f89413345d00ec8e031706228df6e653c7b6396c94591";
            this.ViewCount = 56;
        }

exception :
System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException: System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. 

System.Data.MappingException: The mapping and metadata information for EntityContainer 'MyContext' no longer matches the information used to create the pre-generated views.
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedAddGeneratedViewsInEntityViewContainer(MetadataWorkspace workspace, EntityViewContainer entityViewContainer, Dictionary`2 extentMappingViews)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedCollectViewsFromObjectCollection(MetadataWorkspace workspace, Dictionary`2 extentMappingViews)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGetGeneratedViews(EntityContainer container)
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace, StorageMappingItemCollection storageMappingItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetGeneratedView(EntitySetBase extent)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(Node node, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ScanTableOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ScanTableOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitPhysicalOpDefault(PhysicalOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process()
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(DbCommandTree ctree, List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
```